# Combining Rewrite Rules - http to https AND all links to one file while maintaining clean URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, https

Over the past few days, I have read quite a few forums and StackOverflow answers on rewriting URLs in apache.conf and converting http to https using rewrites.  Thanks to StackOverflow, I have figured out how to do both separately.  Unfortunately, I haven't found a solution that can combine the two while allowing me to keep my clean URL appearance AND while letting me pass a variable to page in a hidden manner.

Here is the current directory part of my apache.conf file:

```
<Directory /home/tim/example>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sort-url.php?rt=$1
</Directory>
```

I currently pass of "https://example.com/CA/Los-Angeles" to a file called "sort-url.php", where I get the "rt" variable, explode it into an array using the "/", and then use the variables like $route_array[0] for "CA" and $route_array[1] = "Los-Angeles".  Right now, the user will never see "sort-url.php", so my URLs always look clean.  I want to keep this same effect, but convert http to https for all sites.

I found this code to convert to https if I substitute this rewrite rule for the other rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/sort-url.php?rt=$1 [R,L]
```

But, this causes "sort-url.php?rt=CA/Los-Angeles" to show up in the URL.  If I get rid of the "sort-url.php in the rewrite rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

It won't know to route all requests to the sort-url.php file, but it will look like the clean link I want with https.

Am I going about it the wrong way?  Is it possible to combine the two rules while maintaining a clean URL?

Thank you in advance,
Tim

ADDITION - Here are my virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:12345>
   ServerName example.com
   Redirect / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:80>
   ServerName example.com
   Redirect / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:443>
   ServerName example.com
   DocumentRoot /home/tim/example
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.key
   SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/sf_bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L] is good, and also add <Directory /home/tim/example>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sort-url.php?rt=$1
</Directory>
 in vhost definitions for https.

Comment: Thank you, jacouh. I'm sorry, I am not clear what you mean (although I did try to do what you said).  I added my vhost info above.  You are suggesting to change the directory to this:
<Directory /home/tim/example>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</Directory>

Comment: And for the last VH to do this:
<VirtualHost XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:443>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/tim/example
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/sf_bundle.crt

    <Directory /home/tim/example> 
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteBase / 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sort-url.php?rt=$1  
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood a key part, but that doesn't seem to work for me.  Sorry for the triple comment.

Comment: I think that the OP can work out a vhost solution instead of DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess.

Comment: I would prefer to work out a VH solution, but I guess I'm willing to accept anything at this point.  Trying to mess with .htaccess now, but I would prefer to stick with VH.  I wonder what I'm missing.....

Answer (score 0):

- Enable .htaccess if not already enabled.

**Try this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`:**

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sort-url.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: When I use that code, I get this in Firefox "The page isn't redirecting properly.  Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete. This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies."

Comment: This may be the good solution. But why apache.conf <Directory> does not work for :443 server and RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/sort-url.php?rt=$1 [R,L].

Comment: Jacouh, I think what you wrote still has the "sort-url.php" show up in the URL bar.  I want it to not have that show up but instead keep "https://example.com/CA/Los-Angeles".

Comment: @timfstl: Since changing Apache config required restart every time I suggest using above code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` (make sure .htaccess is enabled)

Comment: I get the same error as for the solution below from jacouh when I try this method.... "Not Found. The requested URL /CA was not found on this server. Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) Server at example.com Port 80".  Any thoughts?  404 error if that helps.

Comment: Which raises suspicion whether this .htaccess is being read or not. **Make sure if your `.htaccess` is enabled by putting same garbage text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?**

Comment: It does not appear to work.  I can spend my time looking into why this would be, but I would rather see if I can find a VH solution instead of messing with a .htaccess file.  I used to use one long ago and would prefer not to go back to it if possible.  Do you have any ideas on how to make the VH work?  If I can't figure this one out, I'll move on to trying to troubleshoot .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest suppressing Directory clause (COMMENT), and this in vhosts:

```
<VirtualHost XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:80>
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAlias *.example.com
   DocumentRoot /home/tim/example

   Redirect / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:443>
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAlias *.example.com
   DocumentRoot /home/tim/example

   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.key
   SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/sf_bundle.crt

   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sort-url.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks again, jacouh.  This is what I got "Not Found The requested URL /CA was not found on this server.  Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) Server at example.com Port 80".  I am not sure why is says Port 80 or if that matters.  I am using a load balancer with two servers where the traffic comes to LB on port 80, I think.  404 Error if that helps.

Comment: ? :443 and :80 are different servers. I added ServerAlias *.example.com

Comment: I tried this just now.  Same error as above.  I have two servers with a load balancer.  Both have the same apache.conf file with the IP addresses changed to match the server.  I'm really stuck on this one.  Been driving me nuts for days.....

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Can you please elaborate?  To be clear, I have always used rewrite in every example I've tried.

Comment: Is it working without those RewriteRules in vhosts? have you commented Directory clauses? You should start with a working config. And then add more and more.

Comment: I had everything working when using the directory.  I am trying to add "more and more" now.  I got the site to redirect to sort-url.php.  I could not combine that with the http to https redirect without seeing "sort-url.php".  You can check out my site at https://highschoolclothing.com.  I am playing on it now, but the problem I want to fix is when someone types "highschoolclothing.com".

Comment: See how this link looks:  https://highschoolclothing.com/CA/Los-Angeles/Laces/Unicorns/Shirts-and-Hoodies/Sports-And-Activities/Staff-And-Students/110548/   I would like to be able to redirect http://highschoolclothing.com/CA/Los-Angeles to https.  While keeping the link appearance.  Without seeing "sort-url.php".  I have yet to see a solution online anywhere that has worked for me and this is not the first time I've tried this exercise.  I REALLY appreciate any guidance or suggestions you might have.

Comment: I am pretty sure all of my testing has been on one IP address.  I don't think the config for the other IP matters since I am sure I am working on the master server and not the clone.  Does that make sense?

Comment: If I comment out the directory and add your code above, with the slash, it does not redirect http://highschoolclothing.com to https and it also gives me the 404 error for any other page.

Comment: With this:          RewriteEngine On

       RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sort-url.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
 ?

Comment: Once again, same issues as above.  does not redirect to https for homepage.  Gives a 404 error with any other page.  The only thing that has been kind of close so far is what I started with.  I can't seem to get any closer with these.  Are you sure commenting out the directory is the way to go?  Why does it not have the same effect when the rules are the same, I wonder?

Comment: Where else might there be rules that could conflict?  Any other files I should be looking at?

Comment: I copied these RewriteRules from a Working Server for your test. You may have other rules in conflict with those rules. In .htaccess, ohter rules in vhosts, ... all that apache will read when restarting by /etc/init.d/apache2 restart. Or read (.htaccess) for each page (URL).

Comment: Hi jacouh and anubhava.  Thanks again for your help.  Not sure if you see the updates automatically on this post, but I wanted to let you know I finally found a solution.  What you two suggested was great, but my own LB configuration was affecting everything and I didn't understand that.  See my solution above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it appears my load balancer configuration (SSL termination on LB, port 80, etc.) was throwing me for a loop and "X-Forwarded-Proto" was the answer I needed.  Here is my updated directory part:

```
<Directory /home/tim/example>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sort-url.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
</Directory>
```